# Group by one column compare another column and add values to a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have these columns:
`index`, `area`, `key0`

I have to group by index (it is a normal column called index) in order to take the rows that have the same value.

```
#all the ones, all the twos, etc
```

Some of them (rows) are unique though.

About the ones that are not unique now:

What I have done so far:

I have to check with a `group by` which of the groups have the largest area and give its respected `key0` value to the others in its group in a new column called `key1`.

The unique values are going to still have the same value they had in `key0` in the now `key1` column

First I checked which of those occur more than once in order to know which are going to form groups.

```
df['index'].value_counts()[df['index'].value_counts()>1]



359    9
391    8
376    7
374    6
354    5
446    4
403    4
348    4
422    4
424    4
451    4
364    3
315    3
100    3
245    3
345    3
247    3
346    3
347    3
351    3
```

which worked fine. The thing now is how to do the rest?

the dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": [1,2,3,5,1,2,3,3,3], "area": 
[50,60,70,80,90,100,10,20,70], "key0": ["1f",2,"3d",4,5,6,7,8,9]})
print df

# INPUT
area  index key0
  50      1   1f
  60      2    2
  70      3   3d
  80      5    4
  90      1    5
 100      2    6
  10      3    7
  20      3    8
  70      3    9
```

[dataset](http://www.mediafire.com/file/x4q5k7xuztq6o3w/p.zip)

```
import geopandas as gpd
inte=gpd.read_file('in.shp')


inte["rank_gr"] = inte.groupby("index")["area_of_poly"].rank(ascending = False, method = 
"first")
inte["key1_temp"] = inte.apply(lambda row: str(row[""]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0
else "", axis = 1)
inte["CAD_ADMIN_FINAL"] = inte.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
print (inte[["area_of_poly", "index", "CAD_ADMIN", "CAD_ADMIN_FINAL"]])
```

Comment: I would need to see part of the original dataframe and your expected output

Comment: Well the dataframe and the result is like the poster below but I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with the data you provided. And it works. Haven't found any "key0" column so assumed it can be "CAD_ADMIN". "AREA" is only one value so I took "AREA_2".

```
import geopandas as gpd

# set your path
path = r"p\in.shp"

p = gpd.read_file(path)
p["rank_gr"] = p.groupby("index")["AREA_2"].rank(ascending = False, method = 
"first")
p["key1_temp"] = p.apply(lambda row: str(row["CAD_ADMIN"]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0 
else "", axis = 1)
p["key1"] = p.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
p = p[["AREA_2", "index", "CAD_ADMIN", "key1"]]
print(p.sort_values(by = ["index"]))

      AREA_2  index CAD_ADMIN     key1
1.866706e+06      0   0113924  0113924
1.559865e+06      1   0113927  0113926
1.593623e+06      1   0113926  0113926
1.927774e+06      2   0113922  0113922
1.927774e+06      3   0113922  0113922
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"index": [1,2,3,5,1,2,3,3,3], "area": 
[50,60,70,80,90,100,10,20,70], "key0": ["1f",2,"3d",4,5,6,7,8,9]})
print df

# INPUT
area  index key0
  50      1   1f
  60      2    2
  70      3   3d
  80      5    4
  90      1    5
 100      2    6
  10      3    7
  20      3    8
  70      3    9

df["rank_gr"] = df.groupby("index")["area"].rank(ascending = False, method = 
"first")
df["key1_temp"] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row["key0"]) if row["rank_gr"] == 1.0 
else "", axis = 1)
df["key1"] = df.groupby("index")["key1_temp"].transform("sum")
print df[["area", "index", "key0", "key1"]]


# OUTPUT
area  index key0 key1
  50      1   1f    5
  60      2    2    6
  70      3   3d   3d
  80      5    4    4
  90      1    5    5
 100      2    6    6
  10      3    7   3d
  20      3    8   3d
  70      3    9   3d
```

Comment: It says `KeyError: ('', 'occurred at index 0')` by the way I use Python 3 and although I put the parenthesis where needed it gives this error.

Comment: Code works in python 3.6 pandas 0.20.3. Which version do you have? 
You have the error on your data or this table from example?

Comment: Actually on your data it indeed works but on my data( my mistake I did not provided them) it doesn't. If you care you can download the data and try it yourself:check the post for the updated version with my data.You just have to install geopandas to deal with the file.Thanks